# TrueFile.umount(archive) goes to finally method

Tags: java, truezip

I am using truezip (7.7.9 version) to update an archive file in my Java code.

I am doing the above said in a try catch block
when the `TFile.umount` is invoked, the code automatically skips the immediate lines in the `try` block and goes to `finally`.

Would really be helpful if anyone suggests a solution.

```
try
{
    //to commit the changes in archive file
    TFile.umount(archive);
    upload(archive); //this line never executed so, I've added this method to finally block.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    uncommitted = true;
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"errorcommitting"+archive.getName());
}
finally
{
    if(!uncommitted)
        upload(archive);
}
```

I've made changes to the code to make it workable, but it doesn't feel correct to do it in this way.

Comment: Post the code, please

Comment: done @AdamMichalik

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but it seems to work as intended since the finally block is always executed.

Comment: Is this your real code? `TFile.umount(archive)` is the last line in the `try` block, so the next instruction in successful execution is to execute the `finally` block. What's the issue then?

Comment: could you please check now ...?  @AdamMichalik

Comment: Just a wild guess - is there an `Error` (not `Exception`) being thrown? Can you try catching `Throwable` instead of `Exception` and seeing if it enters the `try` block then?

Comment: tried but same thing happens  @AdamMichalik